# Как запретить делать двойной клик по кнопке?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть кнопка (*.show-more*), при нажатии на которую показываются/скрываются строки таблицы.

```
document.querySelector('#tchests tr.show-more').onclick = function() {
    // Много кода, отвечающего за показ/скрытие строк таблицы
}
```

Если на эту кнопку быстро нажать два раза, то возникают глюки, которые описывать я здесь не буду, т.к. вопрос не в этом. Вопрос заключается в том, *как запретить делать двойной клик по кнопке?* Я попробовал остановить выполнение кода **onclick** путём вставки в функцию события **ondblclick** с `return: false`, но это не помогло:

```
document.querySelector('#tchests tr.show-more').onclick = function() {
    this.ondblclick = function() { return false; }
    // Много кода, отвечающего за показ/скрытие строк таблицы
}
```

Comment: Это всё та же таблица из прошлого вопроса?

Comment: Почти. Реальная таблица более сложная. Если хотите, можете попробовать написать решение на примере моей таблицы из прошлого вопроса. Но, вообще, мой текущий вопрос не столько о таблицах, сколько о предотвращении тех глюков моего когда, которые будут, если пользователь осуществит двойной клик. Итого: я просто хочу, чтобы при двойном клике ничего не происходило.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener( 'click', clickHandler );

function clickHandler(){
  if( clickHandler.cantClick ) return;
  clickHandler.cantClick = true;
  
  doSomething();
  
  setTimeout(()=>{
    clickHandler.cantClick = false;
  }, 500 ); // разница времени второго клика
}

function doSomething(){
  console.log('clicked');
}
```

```html
<button>Нажми меня</button>
```

Comment: А, не подскажете, существуют ли более красивое решения?

И можно ли как-то тело функции вставить сразу после `document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {`...
Вообще, я знаю, что можно. Просто не знаю, что тогда использовать вместо _clickHandler_ .

Comment: @МихаилТестов анонимную функцию можно назвать. Просто после слова function пишите её название перед скобкой. А насчёт красивости - думаю код должен быть верным и читабельным, а красота у каждого своя.

Comment: Т.е. вот так?
`document.querySelector('#tchests tr.show-more').addEventListener('click', function eve() { if(eve.cantClick) return; eve.cantClick = true; ...код... setTimeout(function() { eve.cantClick = false; }, 500 );` Хочу также обратить ваше внимание, что при первом клике _eve.cantClick === undefined_. Это соответствует канонам? Просто я перфекционист..

Comment: @МихаилТестов да. Насчёт undefined - всё с этим в порядке, ничего предпринимать дополнительно не нужно.

Comment: Как думаете, а может мне заменить `document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', function eve() { });` на `document.querySelector('#button').onclick = function eve() { };` ?

Comment: @МихаилТестов это мелочи, так можно вечно туда-сюда переставлять и наводить якобы-марафет. смысла или разницы в этом нет.

Comment: Хорошо. Большое спасибо за помощь. Если разницы особой нет, то буду использовать `document.querySelector('#button').onclick = function eve() { };`